# writeToFile:atomically: not saving new plist data

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io, nsfilemanager

I am using `writeToFile:atomically:` to update the value of a key in my plist by 1 every time the app is launched. I put this code in `viewDidLoad`, which reads the string value of the key, gets the numeric value of that string, increases it by 1, converts it back to a string, and writes that as the new string for that key, but when I read it again it seems to have not updated. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I don't need a special framework for `writeToFile:atomically:`, do I?

Here is the code:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DaysLaunched.plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DaysLaunched" ofType:@"plist"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error];
}

NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

NSMutableDictionary *data1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

NSString *currentNumberOfDays = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[plistDict objectForKey:@"numberOfDays"]];
NSLog(@"currentNumberOfDays = %@", currentNumberOfDays); //0

int days = [currentNumberOfDays intValue];
days ++;
currentNumberOfDays = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", days];

[data1 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"numberOfDays"] forKey:currentNumberOfDays];
NSLog(@"currentNumberOfDays = %@", currentNumberOfDays); //1


[data1 writeToFile: path atomically:YES];

currentNumberOfDays = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[plistDict objectForKey:@"numberOfDays"]];
NSLog(@"currentNumberOfDays = %@", currentNumberOfDays); //0 ??????? writeToFile isn't working?
```

And here is a screenshot of "DaysLaunched.plist" in my 'Supporting Files' folder, (I've also verified that the plist file name is spelled exactly the same way I spelled it in my code, via Copy-Paste)
[image]

The original plist file is also in my 'Copy Bundle Resources' in targets.

[image]

Comment: Is `writeToFile:atomically:` returning `YES`? Is the `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` call returning `YES`? If not, what does the error say?

Comment: @JoshCaswell, It's succeeding. No error was returned. I'm not sure how to check if writeToFile is returning 'YES', can you guide me in doing so?

Comment: Side note - why is `numberOfDays` a string and not a number? Why do all of the conversions? If it's a number then use a number. And please get rid of all of the needless calls to `stringWithFormat:` in your code. Most aren't needed.

Comment: (I'm slightly afraid that this has something to do with it being in viewDidLoad... in the past I've had code that doesn't work in viewDidLoad but if I move it to viewDidAppear it will work... I'm going to test that theory now)

Comment: I think you have swapped parameters at `[data1 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"numberOfDays"] forKey:currentNumberOfDays];`, try `[data1 setObject:currentNumberOfDays forKey:@"numberOfDays"];`

Comment: How to check if it's returning `YES`? Uh, put the return value in a variable and look at its value.

Comment: @rmaddy, it's a string because when I made it a number and tried checking the value later on saying `if ([plistDict objectForKey:@"numberOfDays"] == 5) {` xCode was giving me an error. - The string with format was just my attempt at debugging the code, originally I didn't have any of those.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw That's because as a number it is an `NSNumber`. You would need `if ([plistDict[@"numberOfDays"] intValue] == 5) {`.

Comment: Consider using a getter and setter, so your code in ViewDidLoad will be a single line `numberOfDays++`. Also, consider using `NSUserDefaults` instead of your own plist file.

Comment: @Mats Thankyou very much! That was the problem indeed! Silly me :)

Comment: BTW - when you write out the new plist, it is being written to the Documents directory (which is correct). So looking at the plist file in the bundle is kind of pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake while setting your data.

You should do:

```
[data1 setObject:currentNumberOfDays forKey:@"numberOfDays"];
```

instead of:

```
[data1 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"numberOfDays"] forKey:currentNumberOfDays];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DaysLaunched.plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DaysLaunched" 
                                                       ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error];
}

NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSInteger days = [plistDict[@"numberOfDays"] integerValue];

plistDict[@"numberOfDays"] = [@(++days) stringValue];

[plistDict writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
```